# Ceiling fan with remote

Tags: lighting, fans

I have a 60" 12 blade ceiling fan with a remote. I tried to wire it up and it doesn't work. My Brother-in-law suggested that I wire it up without using the remote. I have 2 switches that operate the fan. Can this be done? The reason I'm asking is the color of the wires are NOT black, white, blue and ground. I have red, black, ground and yellow. Can this wired up?

Comment: A picture of the wiring will help.  Are the red black ground and yellow out of the ceiling or the fan?  Is what you are calling ground actually a bare copper wire?  Also where on this earth are you?

Comment: Can you post the make and model of your fan?